# Cannot locate class of installed package

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-package

I'm writing a laravel package which contains [spatie/laravel-sitemap](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap).

I already included several external packages and I didn't encountered any issues, but for some reason I'm not able to integrate this one.

What I did is the usual:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-sitemap
```

Then I have created a Console command that have as handle method the following content:

```
public function handle()
{
    SitemapGenerator::create(config('app.url'))
        ->configureCrawler(function (Crawler $crawler) {
            $crawler->ignoreRobots();
        })
        ->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));

    $this->line('<info>Sitemap generated');
}
```

when I execute the command registered as:

```
php artisan myapp:sitemap
```

I get:

```
 Class "Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator" not found
```

The reference imported are:

```
use Spatie\Crawler\Crawler;
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;
```

I also tried `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`, same problem.

Any help?

Comment: maybe try Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator::create instead of SitemapGenerator::create

Comment: @jmvcollaborator same .. "Class "Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator" not found"

Answer (score 1):

register package class in providers array in config/app.php

```
Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider;
```

in the bottom of app.php file

i hope it was useful.

Comment: I've added this line but same issue

Comment: i will try the package and i will update the answer if there any solution

Comment: Yes, but you should test the package creating a laravel package, not installing it directly on the project. Because I tried to install the package directly on the probject and it works, the issue is raised when is installed on another package

Comment: i have no knowledge about creating laravel packages so i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you can publish package using this.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider" --tag=sitemap-config
```

then

```
composer dump-autoload
```

for more details please check the document `https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap` under `Configuration`

Comment: When I run the command above I get: `No publishable resources for tag [sitemap-config].`

Comment: have you installed package using this `composer require spatie/laravel-sitemap` then only you can publish package

Comment: I have installed using that command, why I get no publishable resources?